# Disable file type extension ribbon tab on windows explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ribbon, windows-10-quick-access

I've searched for an answer on this site but op never clarified their problem and it's really bugging me now. Is there a way to disable the little play/manage tabs on the Windows Explorer ribbon?

[image: tabs 1]

[image: tabs 2]

[image: tabs 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to modify Windows Explorer.

If you do not like the way it behaves, there are many free alternatives.

See
[Alternatives to File Explorer](https://alternativeto.net/software/windows-explorer/?license=free&platform=windows)
for a list of 118 alternatives.

Comment: @echips As the question has been answered so that info you seek is provided - in this case it being "no can do" - you should [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it. A good practice even when the answer isn't what you'd like to hear :-) It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and check at least the Asking and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work. Q&A sites are quite different from discussion forums :-)